# Suppose A (non-empty) is bounded below. Let -A denote the set of all -x for x in A. Prove that -A (non-empty) is bounded above, and that...

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have been asked to prove the following in my real analysis class:

Suppose $A \not= \emptyset$ is bounded below. Let $-A$ denote the set of all $-x$ for $x \in A$. Prove that $A \not= \emptyset$ is bounded above, and that $-sup(-A)$ is the greatest lower bound of A.

I am not quite sure where to begin.

Thanks!

Comment: There are two things you're asked to prove. Begin with the first of them.

Comment: You are aware that if $a< b$ then $-b < -a$, I hope?